# Dockerfile RUN command returning "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, docker, build, dockerfile

Trying to create a Dockerfile to create a system that includes a custom build of Python 3 on a CentOS 7 System. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y upgrade
RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
RUN yum -y install zlib-devel bzip2-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl-devel
ADD http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz Python-3.5.2.tgz

RUN ["tar","zxf","Python-3.5.2.tgz"]
WORKDIR "/Python-3.5.2"
RUN "./configure --prefix=/usr/local"
RUN "make"
RUN "make altinstall"
RUN ["rm","-rf","Python-3.5.2"]

RUN yum -y clean headers &&\
yum -y clean packages &&\
yum -y clean metadata

COPY pack/*.py /usr/src/StorageService/

RUN ["/usr/local/bin/pip3.5","install","virtualenv"]
WORKDIR "/usr/src/StorageService"
RUN ["virtualenv","--python=python3","--always-copy","SSEnv"]
RUN ["source","SSEnv/bin/activate"]
RUN ["/usr/local/bin/pip3.5","install","requests"]
RUN ["/usr/local/bin/pip3.5","install","gunicorn"]

CMD ["gunicorn","--bind=5000","app"]
```

And its all the way through to the "RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr/local" line and then gives me a "No such file or directory" message.
Snipped:

```
... previous steps etc. ...
Step 8 : RUN tar zxf Python-3.5.2.tgz
 ---> Running in 40f96306f38a
 ---> 95804837192a
Removing intermediate container 40f96306f38a
Step 9 : WORKDIR "/Python-3.5.2"
 ---> Running in d8cff5664038
 ---> 038c6b892731
Removing intermediate container d8cff5664038
Step 10 : RUN "./configure --prefix=/usr/local"
 ---> Running in 49b410bed643
/bin/sh: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c "./configure --prefix=/usr/local"' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

When I launch container 038c6b892731 into a bash session the "./configure --prefix=/usr/local" command works as expected:

```
$ docker run -it 038c6b892731 bash
[root@3aeaea02fede Python-3.5.2]# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
... etc. ...
```

I have tried changing the RUN command to "RUN ["./configure","--prefix=/usr/local"]" with the only change in output being the error message being formatted slightly differently.

This is running under:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604
```

Comment: you may be in another current directory...

Comment: You may want to consider combining multiple `RUN` commands into a single multi-line one. There's a pretty good explanation of why you would want to do that in [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers)

Comment: I actually originally did have a bunch combined. I had separated them out to try and figure out what exactly was going wrong with the build procedure. Now that it is working I will probably end up recombining a bunch for the final version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I run your **Dockerfile** with the same error.

But when I changed from this:

```
     RUN "./configure --prefix=/usr/local"
```

to this:

```
     RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

I still had a problem with `RUN "make"` so you also need to change Dockerfile like this:

```
RUN ["tar","zxf","Python-3.5.2.tgz"]
WORKDIR "/Python-3.5.2"
RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
# changed 
RUN make
# changed 
RUN make altinstall
RUN ["rm","-rf","Python-3.5.2"]
```

And this works for me.
Or you can use the way with `RUN ["xy","ab"]` like @Rao answered.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. 
And I had already tried the RUN ["./configure","--prefix=/usr/local"] form and I got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are trivial changes in the `Dockerfile` as show below:

So, please change below lines
**From:**

```
ADD http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz Python-3.5.2.tgz

RUN ["tar","zxf","Python-3.5.2.tgz"]
WORKDIR "/Python-3.5.2"
RUN "./configure --prefix=/usr/local"
```

**To:**

```
ADD http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz /Python-3.5.2.tgz

RUN ["tar","zxf","/Python-3.5.2.tgz"]
WORKDIR "/Python-3.5.2"
RUN ["./configure", "--prefix=/usr/local"]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, I had tried that form and received the exact same error message.